# Query Activity through API possible values for TargetUpdateType

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

I am trying to create and perform a QueryActivity through the SOAP API. I managed to get it working using 'Overwrite' as the value for the TargetUpdateType attribute.

However I cannot find any documentation on allowed values for this field. To tell you the truth I am not really sure what 'Overwrite' does.

Does anybody know what the possible values and their effect is?

Comment: Can you confirm the object name your querying? I cannot find any object called QueryActivity in the Salesforce documentation? Nor for any field called TargetUpdateType? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

Comment: Please remember to Tag your [ExactTarget](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exacttarget) questions as such to distinguish them from Salesforce questions. To your question. I found [references](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_query_activity/) to it in the ExactTarget documentation, but couldn't tell you what it is for.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the tagging, really sorry I missed that. I found references too, but unfortunately no clear description. I should have included some links in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible values are:

1. Overwrite : truncates target DE, and puts the results of the query in.
2. Append :  adds new values to DE, but does not update records.  Requires a primary key on the DE.
3. Update : adds new values to DE and updates records as needed.  Requires a primary key on the DE.

Hope this helps.